# How to start nginx in Docker on Windows

Tags: docker, nginx

I am using Windows 10 and I have installed Docker and pulled nginx:

`docker pull nginx`

I started nginx with this command:

`docker run -dit --rm --name nginx -p 9001:80 nginx`

And simple page is available on localhost:9001.

I would like to pass nginx.conf file to nginx. Also, I would like to give it a folder root, so that on localhost:9001 I see static page D:/nginx/website_files/index.html. In folder website_files there are also other static pages.

How to pass nginx.conf and folder path to nginx in Docker on Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started using Kitematic and pulled hello-world-nginx. With it I was able to browse files by clicking on Volumes -> /website_files. On path that opens, other static files can be added. After that nginx can be restarted and it increments port by 1. Port number can be seen with `docker ps`.

To change nginx config file, after starting nginx I run this command `docker cp D:/nginx/multi.conf b3375f37a95c:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` where b3375f37a95c is container id obtained from `docker ps` command. After that nginx should be restarted from Kitematic.

If you only want to edit nginx.conf instead of completely changing it, you can first get current conf file with `docker cp b3375f37a95c:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf D:/nginx/multi.conf`, edit multi.conf and than copy it back as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use host volume mapping

`-v <host-directory>:<container-path>`

for example:

`docker run -dit --rm -v d:/data:/data -p 9001:80 nginx /bin/sh`

Comment: It is not working. When I add "/bin/sh" to command, nginx is not started correctly. Also, you haven't mentioned how to pass nginx.conf file to nginx.

Comment: your host dir will have the required file which will be mounted to the container for example: `docker run -d -p 80:80 -v <sites-enabled-dir>:/etc/nginx/conf.d  -v <log-dir>:/var/log/nginx nginx`

Comment: With command `docker run -dit --rm -v D:/multi.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d --name nginx -p 9001:80 nginx` there is an error: docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/D/multi.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"..." at \\\".../etc/nginx/conf.d\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\""
: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.

Comment: I am using Windows. Have you tried using Docker on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in PS :

```
PS C:\> docker run --name myNGinX -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v C:\Docker\Volumes\myNGinX\www\:/etc/nginx/www/:ro -v C:\Docker\Volumes\myNGinX\nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro -d nginx
```